# How can I populate new columns?

Tags: sql, informix, bulkupdate

I added four new columns to a DailyTotals table that already has many rows and I need to populate the new columns with daily totals for each row by querying all daily pawn transactions.

The DailyTotals table looks like this:

```
    tblDailyTotals
    (
    dt_date DATE,       {unique index}
    ...
    dt_P_count INT,
    dt_P_amt DECIMAL(8,2),
    dt_X_count INT,
    dt_X_amt DECIMAL(8,2)
    );
```

The Pawn Transactions table looks like this:

```
    tblPawnTransactions
    (
    ...
    pt_date DATE,       {dups index}
    pt_type CHAR(1), {"P","X"}
    pt_amt DECIMAL(7,2)
    );
```

How would you code the mass update query to populate the four new columns for each daily row in the DailyTotals table?

Comment: Did the table dailyTotals exist before or was is just created? Which columns did you add (and on which table)? With what data should these new columns be populated? And how?

Comment: both tables exist since 01/02/2016. I added the last four columns in tblDailyTotals.

Comment: I need daily  total counts and amounts for pawn types P anf X.

Comment: Table dailyTotals seems to have a unique index. On which column(s) is it? on  dt_date or something else?
Also, please explain in detail what you want to do.
Right now, we only know (parts of) your table schema, but don't know what you want to do exactly. What data should be in `dt_P_count` for example? How can it be calculated? Only you can tell us, what you want to do. What does `{"P", "X"}` mean in the pawns table? I don't understand that syntax

Comment: Do you want to count the numbers of rows per day and save that into daily totals or what? Do you mean `SELECT COUNT(pt_amt) FROM pawns GROUP BY pt_date) ORDER BY pt_date` ? Or sum them using SUM?

Comment: example: total daily count of type P pawns populates dt_P_count where dt_date = pt_date.

Comment: Can someone please accept the code sample edit I submitted? It wont let me commit the edit, thanks.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` like so `SELECT pt_date, SUM( pt_amt ) AS sum, COUNT( pt_type ) AS count WHERE pt_type = 'P'  GROUP BY pt_date` to get the data. Then use an UPDATE on dailyTotals to SET the columns data.
`UPDATE daily SET dt_P_amt = x.

Comment: `UPDATE daily SET dt_P_amt = x.sum, dt_P_count = x.count FROM (SELECT pt_date, SUM( pt_amt ), COUNT( pt_type ) WHERE pt_type = 'P'  GROUP BY pt_date) AS x (pt_date, sum, count) WHERE x.pt_date = dt_date`. Here you use the fact, that you can temporarily NAME tables, for example x here: ` AS x (pt_date, sum, count) ` declares the result of the `SELECT` to be available as temp table x with three columns pt_date, sum and count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some working Informix SQL.  It assumes you have DBDATE='Y4MD-' or equivalent set in the environment — you'll need to adjust the date formats to suit your preferences.

#### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE    tblDailyTotals
    (
    dt_date DATE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,       {unique index}
    dt_other CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    dt_P_count INT,
    dt_P_amt DECIMAL(8,2),
    dt_X_count INT,
    dt_X_amt DECIMAL(8,2)
    );


CREATE TABLE   tblPawnTransactions
    (
    pt_customer INT,
    pt_date DATE,       {dups index}
    pt_type CHAR(1), {"P","X"}
    pt_amt DECIMAL(7,2)
    );

INSERT INTO tblDailyTotals(dt_date, dt_other) VALUES('2017-01-01', 'Other info 2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO tblDailyTotals(dt_date, dt_other) VALUES('2017-01-02', 'Other info 2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO tblDailyTotals(dt_date, dt_other) VALUES('2017-01-03', 'Other info 2017-01-03');
INSERT INTO tblDailyTotals(dt_date, dt_other) VALUES('2017-01-04', 'Other info 2017-01-04');
INSERT INTO tblDailyTotals(dt_date, dt_other) VALUES('2017-01-05', 'Other info 2017-01-05');
INSERT INTO tblDailyTotals(dt_date, dt_other) VALUES('2017-01-06', 'Other info 2017-01-06');
UPDATE tblDailyTotals
   SET dt_P_count = 3, dt_P_amt = 345.67, dt_X_count = 9, dt_X_amt = 291.23
 WHERE dt_date = '2017-01-06';

INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(1, '2017-01-01', 'P', 12.34);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(2, '2017-01-01', 'P', 22.25);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(3, '2017-01-01', 'X', 32.16);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(1, '2017-01-02', 'P', 42.07);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(4, '2017-01-02', 'P', 52.98);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(2, '2017-01-02', 'X', 62.89);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(1, '2017-01-03', 'P', 72.70);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(1, '2017-01-03', 'X', 82.51);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(1, '2017-01-03', 'P', 92.42);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(2, '2017-01-05', 'X', 13.33);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(1, '2017-01-05', 'P', 14.14);
INSERT INTO tblPawnTransactions VALUES(1, '2017-01-05', 'X', 15.05);
```

#### Updates

```
SELECT * FROM tblDailyTotals ORDER BY dt_date;

UPDATE tblDailyTotals
   SET (dt_P_count, dt_P_amt) = ((SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(pt_amt)
                                    FROM tblPawnTransactions AS pt
                                   WHERE pt.pt_date = tblDailyTotals.dt_date
                                     AND pt.pt_type = 'P'
                                ))
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblPawnTransactions AS pt
               WHERE pt.pt_date = tblDailyTotals.dt_date AND pt_type = 'P')
;

UPDATE tblDailyTotals
   SET (dt_X_count, dt_X_amt) = ((SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(pt_amt)
                                    FROM tblPawnTransactions AS pt
                                   WHERE pt.pt_date = tblDailyTotals.dt_date
                                     AND pt.pt_type = 'X'
                                ))
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblPawnTransactions AS pt
               WHERE pt.pt_date = tblDailyTotals.dt_date AND pt_type = 'X')
;
```

The double parentheses are necessary; the outer pair indicates that there is a list of values on the RHS of the SET clause, to match the list of columns in parentheses on the LHS of the SET clause, while the inner parentheses indicate that the values are the result of a SELECT statement.

#### Output for sample data

Before update:

```
2017-01-01  Other info 2017-01-0
2017-01-02  Other info 2017-01-0
2017-01-03  Other info 2017-01-0
2017-01-04  Other info 2017-01-0
2017-01-05  Other info 2017-01-0
2017-01-06  Other info 2017-01-0    3   345.67      9  291.23
```

After update:

```
2017-01-01  Other info 2017-01-0    2   34.59       1   32.16
2017-01-02  Other info 2017-01-0    2   95.05       1   62.89
2017-01-03  Other info 2017-01-0    2   165.12      1   82.51
2017-01-04  Other info 2017-01-0
2017-01-05  Other info 2017-01-0    1   14.14       2   28.38
2017-01-06  Other info 2017-01-0    3   345.67      9  291.23
```

#### Why the EXISTS clause?

What happens if you omit the `WHERE EXISTS(…)` clauses?  Rows which don't have matching entries in the `tblPawnTransactions` table get updated too, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblDailyTotals ORDER BY dt_date;

UPDATE tblDailyTotals
   SET (dt_P_count, dt_P_amt) = ((SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(pt_amt)
                                    FROM tblPawnTransactions AS pt
                                   WHERE pt.pt_date = tblDailyTotals.dt_date
                                     AND pt.pt_type = 'P'
                                ))
 ;

UPDATE tblDailyTotals
   SET (dt_X_count, dt_X_amt) = ((SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(pt_amt)
                                    FROM tblPawnTransactions AS pt
                                   WHERE pt.pt_date = tblDailyTotals.dt_date
                                     AND pt.pt_type = 'X'
                                ))
 ;

SELECT * FROM tblDailyTotals ORDER BY dt_date;
```

This generates:

```
2017-01-01  Other info 2017-01-0    2   34.59       1   32.16
2017-01-02  Other info 2017-01-0    2   95.05       1   62.89
2017-01-03  Other info 2017-01-0    2   165.12      1   82.51
2017-01-04  Other info 2017-01-0    0               0
2017-01-05  Other info 2017-01-0    1   14.14       2   28.38
2017-01-06  Other info 2017-01-0    0               0
```

Notice that the rows for 2017-01-04 and 2017-01-06 both got updated.  Now, if you want those zeroes and nulls in place, that's fine.  If not, use the EXISTS clause.

Comment: your last script without the EXISTS clause worked fine. The amount columns were created NOT NULL. tblDailyTotals also does not have consecutive day rows, as the pawnshop does not open on Sundays and certain holidays. I also think that its possible to update all four columns within one update statement.

Comment: Be cautious; without the EXISTS, it can zap data you didn't want zapped.  You may be OK because of other constraints, but caution is required.  If you can guarantee that there's always at least one P and at least one X record per day (that's in the system), then you can do it all in one.  If there's data missing, you might get zeros and nulls again — which might or might not matter to you.  You can tweak the ideas to suit yourself.  Just be cautious not to damage the operational data (he says, teaching Grandma to suck eggs).

Comment: The bulk update is a run-once script. tblDailyTotals unique rows are only inserted by a script if the shop opens for business. If no pawn transactions occur on open days, the P/X counts and amounts must all have zeros. I have a totals report by date range which adds up these and other daily values.

Comment: I tested your script, sans EXISTS, on a production backup I have and all looks well. If something breaks on the production system, I can undo it since its running on a VM with disk undos. How can grandma zap data if its theres none to zap?

Comment: Despite having all supporting indexes for bulk updating 420 daily total rows by reading ~3,500 pawn transactions, it took a long time to complete. Must be due to the pairwise join architecture most merchant OLTP database servers use.

Comment: The correlated sub queries are not very efficient. If you were working with a modern version of Informix, we could generate the summary values into a temporary table and then MERGE the results in place. Given the context, I'm fairly sure MERGE isn't available as an option.  A temporary table might still be beneficial.  I've not experimented with it though.

Comment: MERGE is not supported in SE 4.10. The rows in tblDailyTotals are already ordered by dt_date ascending since new rows are inserted when the shop opens, so theres no need to sort them before executing the bulk update. However, rows in tblPawnTransactions are clustered by the Customer ID foreign key for faster queries when users want to view and update each customer's pawns.